# Packer - Openstack Builder: Getting "net/http: TLS handshake timeout" error

Tags: ssl, connection-timeout, packer

I am trying to create a Windows image in `Private Openstack Cloud` using Packer.

But the `Openstack identity_endpoint API` which I am providing in my Packer build file is throwing following error: `net/http: TLS handshake timeout`

Could someone please help me here?

Comment: Try to provide a more detailed question so it is possible to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are either supplying the wrong URL or your OpenStack service is down.

Comment: Hi Rickard, Thanks your reply. I am providing the right URL which I have copied from my Openstack API&Security section and the Openstack is also Up and Running.

Comment: The try to `curl` that?

Comment: Then I suggest that you talk to the OpenStack admins or network guys.

Comment: Cool. I will talk to the admins/network guys and thanks a lot for your swift response Rickard. If I found something I will post here.